# How to replace a list item with an new nested list using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I want to replace within a unordered list a list item with a new unordered list:

Before:

```
<ul class="text-error">
<li>    Fish </li>
<li>    Bird </li>
<li     ###Bear,Cat$$$</li>
</ul>
```

The third list item contains a string which I want to transform to an nested list:

```
var missingArray = [];
$( "li:contains('###')", ".text-error" ).each(function(idx, li) {
    var listItem = $(li).text();
    var missingItem = listItem.split('###')[1].split('$$$')[0];
    missingItems = missingItem;
    missingArray = missingItems.split(',');
}); 
if (missingArray.length > 0){
    //remove list item
    $("li:contains('###')", ".text-error" ).each(function(idx, li) {
        $(this).remove();       
    })

    //create ul element
    $("ul.text-error").each(function(idx, li){
        $(this).append($("<ul id='files-error'>").text("Furry:"));
    })

    //include list with missing files
    var fileList = $("#files-error");
    $.each(missingArray, function(key, value){
        fileList.append($("<li class='file-error'>").text(value));
    })      

}
```

However the result I get is:

```
<ul class="text-error">
<ul id="files-error">Furry:</ul>
<li>    Fish </li>
<li>    Bird </li>
<li class="file-error">Bear</li>
<li class="file-error">Cat</li>
</ul>
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and how i should do it correctly?

Comment: Where did the word Furry came from?

Comment: And where is the text "Missing files: "?

Comment: I juste paste all your code into a JSFiddle and I don't know what doesn't work as expected... https://jsfiddle.net/uq31can9/

Comment: I have updated my code. You were right when I pasted my code I forget to change these value to simplify my code.

Comment: Thank you S. I never used jsfidlle before. I see now my code should work, but that it is not doing on my platform. Could be due to that it does not allow nested lists.

Comment: One note about the splits: `split()` isn't the way to remove characters at the first & the end of a string, and also, can raise issues; Suppose you have the string `###text###text$$$`, after doing `split('###')[1]` you'll loss the second `text`. Instead, use [the function `slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), like `str.slice(3).slice(0, -3)` will make `text###text` in the previous example.